# Quisiera saber ¿por qué no puedo realizar la consulta de otra entidad con Sugar ORM en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Estoy realizando un pequeño formulario en el cual implemente Sugar ORM y funciona muy bien con el primer formulario, pero al crear la segunda entidad no puedo consultar los datos guardados.

A continiacion envio la parte del codigo el cual me arroja el siguiente error:

> **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>                                                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList**

De antemano muchas gracias por sus opiniones.

#### manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="aplicacion.android.u.vertex">

    <uses-permission android:name ="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="an droid.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode">
        <activity android:name=".Main" />

        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="dbvertex.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="3" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="aplicacion.android.universidad_distrital.vertex" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Formulario" />
        <activity android:name=".Encuesta" />
        <activity android:name=".consultaformulario"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

#### class RegistroDatosEncuesta

```
package aplicacion.android.u.vertex;

import com.orm.SugarRecord;

/**
 * Created by Android on 02/03/2018.
 */

public class RegistroDatosEncuesta extends SugarRecord {
  public String getCdu1() {
    return cdu1;
  }

  public void setCdu1(String cdu1) {
    this.cdu1 = cdu1;
  }

  public String getR1() {
    return r1;
  }

  public void setR1(String r1) {
    this.r1 = r1;
  }

  public String getR2() {
    return r2;
  }

  public void setR2(String r2) {
    this.r2 = r2;
  }

  public String getR3() {
    return r3;
  }

  public void setR3(String r3) {
    this.r3 = r3;
  }

  public String getR4() {
    return r4;
  }

  public void setR4(String r4) {
    this.r4 = r4;
  }

  public String getR5() {
    return r5;
  }

  public void setR5(String r5) {
    this.r5 = r5;
  }

  public String getR6() {
    return r6;
  }

  public void setR6(String r6) {
    this.r6 = r6;
  }

  public String getR7() {
    return r7;
  }

  public void setR7(String r7) {
    this.r7 = r7;
  }

  public RegistroDatosEncuesta(String cdu1, String r1, String r2, String r3, String r4, String r5, String r6, String r7) {
    this.cdu1 = cdu1;
    this.r1 = r1;
    this.r2 = r2;
    this.r3 = r3;
    this.r4 = r4;
    this.r5 = r5;
    this.r6 = r6;
    this.r7 = r7;
  }

  String  cdu1,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7;

}
```

#### class Encuesta

```
package aplicacion.android.u.vertex;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.List;

public class Encuesta extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button regresar1,c1,e1;
   EditText cdu1,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7;

    public Encuesta() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_encuesta);


        c1         =(Button)findViewById(R.id.c1);
        e1         =(Button)findViewById(R.id.e1);
        regresar1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.regresar1);




        cdu1       =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cdu1);
        r1        = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.r1);
        r2        = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.r2);
        r3        = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.r3);
        r4        = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.r4);
        r5        = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.r5);
        r6        = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.r6);
        r7        = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.r7);



        c1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //List<RegistroDatosEncuesta> RegistroDatoslista =  RegistroDatosEncuesta.listAll(RegistroDatosEncuesta.class);

                List<RegistroDatosEncuesta> R1 =  RegistroDatosEncuesta.find(RegistroDatosEncuesta.class, "cdu1 = ?", cdu1.getText().toString());

                    RegistroDatosEncuesta RegistroD3 = R1.get(0);
                    r1.setText(RegistroD3.getR1());
                    r2.setText(RegistroD3.getR2());
                    r3.setText(RegistroD3.getR3());
                    r4.setText(RegistroD3.getR4());
                    r5.setText(RegistroD3.getR5());
                    r6.setText(RegistroD3.getR6());
                    r7.setText(RegistroD3.getR7());




            }
        });


        e1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onClick(View view) {

                                      RegistroDatosEncuesta RegistroD3 = new RegistroDatosEncuesta
                                              (cdu1.getText().toString(),r1.getText().toString(),r2.getText().toString(),
                                                      r3.getText().toString(),r4.getText().toString(),r5.getText().toString(),
                                                      r6.getText().toString(),r7.getText().toString());



                                      RegistroD3.save();






                                  }
                              });


                regresar1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent regresar1 = new Intent(Encuesta.this, Main.class);
                        startActivity(regresar1);

                    }
                });



    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

El problema mencionado se produce al tratar de obtener un elemento en la primera posicion (indice cero) de una Array que en realidad esta vacio.

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException

El problema se presenta en este punto, al obtener el array de objetos `RegistroDatosEncuesta` y tratar de obtener el valor en el indice cero del array

```
List<RegistroDatosEncuesta> R1 =  RegistroDatosEncuesta.find(RegistroDatosEncuesta.class, "cdu1 = ?", cdu1.getText().toString());

RegistroDatosEncuesta RegistroD3 = R1.get(0);
```

debes revisar la razon por la cual no obtienes valores para el array, pero en este caso debes validar en caso de no existir elementos, puedes usar el metodo [isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#isEmpty())

> [isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#isEmpty()) Retorna `true` si la lista no contiene elementos.

```
 c1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //List<RegistroDatosEncuesta> RegistroDatoslista =  RegistroDatosEncuesta.listAll(RegistroDatosEncuesta.class);

                List<RegistroDatosEncuesta> R1 =  RegistroDatosEncuesta.find(RegistroDatosEncuesta.class, "cdu1 = ?", cdu1.getText().toString());

                if(R1.isEmpty()){

                  //* No existen elementos en el ArrayList.  

                 }else{
                    RegistroDatosEncuesta RegistroD3 = R1.get(0);
                    r1.setText(RegistroD3.getR1());
                    r2.setText(RegistroD3.getR2());
                    r3.setText(RegistroD3.getR3());
                    r4.setText(RegistroD3.getR4());
                    r5.setText(RegistroD3.getR5());
                    r6.setText(RegistroD3.getR6());
                    r7.setText(RegistroD3.getR7());
                 }    



            }
        });
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.